# display data in tables in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I have narrowed down to the following , if anyone can help me pointing out how i can convert the following into table view that would be awesome. Following html is extended from the base.html

```
{% block page_content %}


<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="card mb-2">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.pk %}"
                   class="btn btn-primary">
                    Read More
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Need help with displaying data in gridview . I m new to all this. I m able to read and display the data on a page from mongodb but need to display in a table.

million $ question for me now is where should i be adjusting the following snippet in my code to give me gridview

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
        <th>Field N</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item.field1 }}</td>
        ...
        <td>{{ item.fieldN }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.project_index, name = "project_index"),
    path ("<project_detail>/",views.project_detail, name = "project_detail"),
    #path("<int:pk>/", views.project_detail, name = "project_detail"),
]
```

My model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    urls = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #image = models.FilePathField(path="/img")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "spiderCollection1"
```

additional tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Project
import itertools

class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        title = tables.Column("title")
        desc = tables.Column("desc")
        urls = tables.Column("urls")
```

following is views.py

```
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from django.shortcuts import render
from projects.models import Project
from projects.tables import ProjectTable

# Create your views here.
class ProjectListView(SingleTableView):
    model = Project
    table_class = ProjectTable
    template_name = '/projects.html'

def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        "projects":projects
    }
    return render (request, 'project_index.html',context)
    #return render (request, 'project_index.html',locals())

def project_detail(request, pk):
    #project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    project = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        "project": project
        #'personal_portfolio':project
    }
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html',context)
```

my main base.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Portfolio</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

              <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--<style>
        h1 {
            border: 5px solid red;
            }

        h2 {
            border: 4px dotted blue;
            }
        div {
            border: double;
            }
      </style>
      -->


</nav>

<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and now project_index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%load render_table from django_tables %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}


<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="card mb-2">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.pk %}"
                   class="btn btn-primary">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your html file should render the table. You load django_tables but it doesn’t look like you actually display the the table anywhere. Look at the django_table docs regarding rendering your table in the html file.

Comment: Thats what i m doing following the django tables2 docs from https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html. But i m stuck with gridview not listview.

Can suggest what can i do to display in gridview or table format? Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to display a table without using the django-table2 package follow the first part of the answer. If the goal is to use django-table2 then jump to Part II:

**Part I**

Based on your colde, let us use the example snippet, and edit it in order to display your `project` data in an HTML table...

Starting with your `project_index.html`, we need create the skeleton of the html table using `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<th>` tags, and then to loop over the passed `projects` context variable and add entries to the table using the `<td>` tag. And because you are using the bootstrap framework, we will need the row and the column divss to display the table correctly.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}

<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for project in projects %}
           <td><strong>{{ forloop.counter }} </strong></td>
           <td><strong>{{ project.title}</strong></td>
           <td>{{ project.description} <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a> </td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Make sure that your `url.py` points to the function `project_index`

To learn more check:

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

**Part II**

Django-table2 is a package that provides an app and middleware to generate html tables. In order to use it in your app make the following changes to your `project_index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}


<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    {% render_table projects %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The code above will use the html template provided by django-table2 for rendering tables, defined in your class ProjectTable

```
class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"  
        ...
```

If you want to use a custom rendering you will need to set the template_name of the ProjectTable to your custom.html:

```
 class ProjectTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        template_name = "custom.html"  
        ...
```

Now create `custom.html` and add the code that will actually iterate over the items of the projects context variable. Maybe something like this (copied from the django_tables2/semantic.html)... Make changes you want to this template.

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block table-wrapper %}
<div class="ui container table-container">
    {% block table %}
        <table {% render_attrs table.attrs class="ui celled table" %}>
            {% block table.thead %}
            {% if table.show_header %}
                <thead {{ table.attrs.thead.as_html }}>
                    <tr>
                    {% for column in table.columns %}
                        <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>
                            {% if column.orderable %}
                                <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a>
                            {% else %}
                                {{ column.header }}
                            {% endif %}
                        </th>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}
            {% endblock table.thead %}
            {% block table.tbody %}
                <tbody {{ table.attrs.tbody.as_html }}>
                {% for row in table.paginated_rows %}
                    {% block table.tbody.row %}
                    <tr {{ row.attrs.as_html }}>
                        {% for column, cell in row.items %}
                            <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{% if column.localize == None %}{{ cell }}{% else %}{% if column.localize %}{{ cell|localize }}{% else %}{{ cell|unlocalize }}{% endif %}{% endif %}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endblock table.tbody.row %}
                {% empty %}
                    {% if table.empty_text %}
                    {% block table.tbody.empty_text %}
                    <tr><td colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">{{ table.empty_text }}</td></tr>
                    {% endblock table.tbody.empty_text %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            {% endblock table.tbody %}
            {% block table.tfoot %}
            <tfoot {{ table.attrs.tfoot.as_html }}>
                {% if table.has_footer %}
                <tr>
                {% for column in table.columns %}
                    <td {{ column.attrs.tf.as_html }}>{{ column.footer }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
                {% block pagination %}
                    {% if table.page and table.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                    <tr>
                    <th colspan="{{ table.columns|length }}">
                        <div class="ui right floated pagination menu">
                            {% if table.page.has_previous %}
                                {% block pagination.previous %}
                                <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=table.page.previous_page_number %}" class="icon item">
                                    <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
                                </a>
                                {% endblock pagination.previous %}
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if table.page.has_previous or table.page.has_next %}
                                {% block pagination.range %}
                                    {% for p in table.page|table_page_range:table.paginator %}
                                        {% if p == '...' %}
                                            <a href="#" class="item">{{ p }}</a>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=p %}" class="item {% if p == table.page.number %}active{% endif %}">
                                                {{ p }}
                                            </a>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endblock pagination.range %}
                            {% endif %}

                            {% if table.page.has_next %}
                                {% block pagination.next %}
                                <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=table.page.next_page_number %}" class="icon item">
                                    <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
                                </a>
                                {% endblock pagination.next %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock pagination %}
            </tfoot>
            {% endblock table.tfoot %}
        </table>
    {% endblock table %}
</div>
{% endblock table-wrapper %}
```

Here make sure your `urls.py` includes:

```
...
path("projects/", ProjectListView.as_view())
...
```

for more refer to:

- https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html
- https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/semantic.html

Comment: Hey , thanks alot for explaining it to me, really appreciate it. 
But i m seeing the same results. Any ideas what cani be missing. I cleared the cache. restarted the app. anything else.
Actually i used your given file but didnt worked :( ...getting on me nerves.... 
I have a gut feeling i m very close.

Comment: ok i have found another issue,
- page is displaying everything from the base.html
- somehow project_index.html is not even rendered. What ever i put in project_index.html is not even shown up there on the page. 
What should be done to resolve this? And what could have been missed out?

Comment: i have got base.html and project_index.html (extended from base.html)
no matter what changes done in project_index.html nothing is shown on web page e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/ . This webpage is only showing whatever is in base.html. The base.html can b seen up. 
base.html has the following that refers to project_index.html 
 <div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
but i doubt this code is successfully calling project_index.html (updated code that u helped me)
Seems to be larger problem. Any ideas? So the problem is still there

Comment: Ah ok. Can you please share your routing file: url.py add it to the original question please!

Comment: so... you are mixing native Django code with django-table2 code, My advise is to stop using the django-table2 code until you get some control over Django. 

 So in your urls.py replace:
path("projects/", ProjectsListView.as_view()) 

 with:

path("projects/", project_index)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the case of native Django code, and the second using Django-table2 package. I hope this helps you further...

Comment: Hi Ouss, 
Thanks for your help, here is my urls.py from project
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', include("projects.urls")),
 #   path('projects01/',ProjectListView.as_view()),
  #  path('app01/', include("app01.urls")),
]
`

Comment: here is my urls.py from my app
`from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.project_index, name = "project_index"),
    path ("<project_detail>/",views.project_detail, name = "project_detail"),
    #path("<int:pk>/", views.project_detail, name = "project_detail"),
] `

Comment: Thanks again your the best Ouss

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="center">
<table class="table table-bordered " border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Game</th>
    </tr>
    {% for i in user_data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.favorite_game}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}</table>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).